# How to increase the connection timeout for mysql connection from c# application?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to increase the connection timeout for mysql connection and I can not modify the timeout settings from administrator panel of mysql server. I want to do it within c# application and I noticed that I can read the property **ConnectionTimeout** of **MySqlConnection** class. I would like to know that is there a way to increase the connection time before opening mysql connection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can change `ConnectionString` as below:

```
String connectionString = "Server=myserver; Port=3306; Database=databasename; Uid=userid; Pwd=password;Connection Timeout=30";
```

in the above `Connection String` you can specify the number of seconds as value for `Connection Timeout`

Answer (score 5):

use "**default command timeout**" in your connection string, it works for me

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
default command timeout=20;
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/specifying-default-command-timeout/

Comment: command and connection timeouts are two different things

Answer (score 3):

Check out the  **wait_timeout** parameter for my.ini

Here is the link. restart mysql after changing the value.Why, because There may be multiple my.ini's on your system - make sure you're changing the right one

```
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
```

or

you can define in your connection string

```
String myconnstring = "Server=yourservername; Port=portno; Database=yourdatabasename; Uid=yourUSERID; Pwd=yourpassword;Connection Timeout=120";
```

Answer (score 0):

default command timeout=0 in your connection string does the trick.

String connectionString = "Server=myserver; Port=3306; Database=databasename; Uid=userid; Pwd=password;default command timeout=0";