# MySqlConnector 'Connect Timeout Expired' Xamarin Forms and c#

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

When attempting to retrieve data from a mysql database I come across this error ***'MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Connect Timeout expired.'*** Looking online told me to check the call stack which presented me with this message that I personally don't understand:

> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C#
> 0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125,4   C#
> 0x20 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.39 C#
> 0x12 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:157,13 C#
> 0x6 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__7_0 at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021,49  C#
> 0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19  C#
> 0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6  C#
> 0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4  C#
> 0x11 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.39 C#

Can someone please explain this error and how to fix it? This is what I believe is the problematic code:

```
async void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string enter_email = Email.Text;
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=app;database=travel_logger;port=3306;password=app"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT _Password FROM * WHERE email=" + enter_email);
            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            string data_password = reader.GetString(0);
            if (data_password == Password.Text)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369855/453348

Comment: have you checked if the port for MySQL is open?

Comment: @AmirSabzehparvar how would I check that.

Comment: is the database on the localhost? are you running the code on the same machine?

Comment: I noticed this and switched to my ip address. But I still get the same error

Comment: It is unable to connect.  Verify the ip and port.  Check your firewall.  Try using a MySQL client app on your device to test

Comment: By the way, you have a major SQL injection issue here. You **must** use parameters instead. Furthermore, do not store plain text passwords, salt-and-has it instead. And do not return the password (or hash) back to the client, instead compare it server-side. You also need a `using` for `reader`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using a public ip address rather that I found from Google. I found the correct one from my settings and it worked.
Local host didn't work as the connection was remote

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).